# React routings-url changes. but doesn't render components. when refresh the page it renders perfectly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-redux

This is a famouse problem in react routings. but i have not any solution since last two weeks.this one is big problem and i hope any answer for this cordially. I have three components such as Admin.js, AdminReview.js and AdminDashboard.js as below.

There is my index.js file.

## index.js

```
<Provider store={store}>
    <BrowserRouter basename="/">
        <App/>
    </BrowserRouter>
</Provider>
```

Admin.js file is located at App.js file.There is Admin.js and it have routings.

## Admin.js

```
return(
        <div>
            <BackdropLoading show={this.props.result} />
            <Switch>
                <Route path="/interactions" component={AdminReview} />
                <Route path="/" exact component={AdminDashbord} />
            </Switch>
        </div>
    )
```

I used redux in my Admin.js file as below.

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)( Admin);
```

AdminReview.js and AdminDashboard.js are normal files but there are used redux as  below.

```
export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(AdminReview));

export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(AdminDashbord));
```

withRouter is higher order component and it import using

> react-router-dom

for prevent the block updates according to the react documentation.

I used navbar to navigate to above routes.this is my AdminNavbar.js file.

## AdminNavbar.js

```
<form className="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
                        <ul className="navbar-nav" style={{float: 'right',marginBottom:'-10px'}}>


                            <li id="reviewId" className="nav-item" style={liStyle}>
                                <Link to="/interactions" onClick={this.reviewClick}
                                   className="nav-link js-scroll-trigger"
                                   style={linkStyle}>
                                    <small>Interactions</small>
                                </Link>
                            </li>



                            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

                            <li id="reportId" className="nav-item"
                                style={{cursor: 'pointer', float: 'right', borderBottom: '1px solid transparent'}}>


                                <Link to="/report" onClick={this.reportClick}
                                   className="nav-link js-scroll-trigger"
                                      style={linkStyle}>
                                    <small>Reports</small>
                                </Link>
                            </li>


                            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

                            <li className="nav-item"
                                style={{cursor: 'pointer', float: 'right', paddingTop: '7px'}}>
                                <img src={dollerIcon} alt="icon" style={{width:'20px'}}/>
                                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                            </li>




                            <li id="dashbordId" className="nav-item" style={{
                                cursor: 'pointer',
                                float: 'right',
                                borderBottom: '1px solid transparent',
                                paddingTop: '2%'
                            }}>
                                <ProfileDropdown user="admin"/>

                            </li>


                        </ul>


                    </form>
```

AdminNavbar also used the redux as below.

```
export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(AdminNavbar));
```

i'm reading currently more articles related this, but i can't fix this issue.please anyone can help solve this?

Comment: This guide holds the answers you seek: https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/guides/blocked-updates.md

Comment: @PraveenRaoChavan.G i studied that guide. and i use the withRouter hoc for prevent the blocking. but i don't see any changes? can you give me another solution?

Comment: @ShubhamAgarwalBhewanewala i did that, but the problem is same!

Answer (score 0):

After long testing, me and my friend finally found the solution for this. if we talk about our component structure, it as below.

## index.js

```
<Provider store={store}>
<BrowserRouter basename="/">
    <App/>
</BrowserRouter>
```

## App.js

```
<div>
    <MainLayout/>
</div>
```

## MainLayout.js

```
<div>
    <AdminLayout/>
</div>
```

## AdminLayout.js

```
<div>
        <BackdropLoading show={this.props.result} />
        <Switch>
            <Route path="/interactions" component={AdminReview} />
            <Route path="/" exact component={AdminDashbord} />
        </Switch>
    </div>
```

i use the connect of react redux in MainLayout.js,AdminLayout.js and AdminReview.js and AdminDashboard.js
so i wrapped those with withRouter hoc of

> react-router-dom

it was wrong. we should wrap only the route used components. such as AdminLayout.js. but there is problem, becuase the child components should not be received props because the MainLayout.js also use the connect. so finally i also wrapped the MainLayout.js from withRouter.now i wrapped two component from withRouter such as AdminLayout.js and MainLayout.js. then the routings work perfectly.